# node js stops working on multiple api request from angular and working after restarting the node app

Tags: mysql, node.js, angularjs, api, rest

i am developing an app with node express js and angular js. My angular app makes an api request from node js app server on each route or button click, also a single component or button click may request multiple api to node js app. upon requesting multiple time the data loading is just got stopped and i am not getting result. Also getting status code like 304 and 204.

please check out my api code and subscribe service code.

> constroller.js ///express js

```
  getList: async (req, res) => {
    try{
      const result = await getList(); //from service.js (an sql query)
     
      var serviceCalls = result[0][0];
      return res.set({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).status(200).json({
        success: 1,
        message: 'Successfully Data Fetched',
        data: serviceCalls
      });
    } catch(e){
      return res.json({
        success: 0,
        message: 'No Data Fetched' + ' ' + e.message,
        data: {}
      });
    }
    },
  
  getDetails: async (req, res) => {
    try{
      const id = req.query.id
      const result = await getDetails(id); //from service.js (an sql query)
      var serviceCalls = result[0][0];
      return res.set({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).status(200).json({
        success: 1,
        message: 'Successfully Data Fetched',
        data: serviceCalls
      });
    } catch(e){
      return res.json({
        success: 0,
        message: {text:'No Data Fetched ', errMsg: e.message},
        data: {}
      });
    }
    },

  getTroubles: async (req, res) => {
      try{
        const id = req.query.id
        const result = await getTroubles(id); //from service.js (an sql query)
        var complaintData = result[0][0];
          
        return res.set({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).status(200).json({
          success: 1,
          message: 'Successfully Data Fetched',
          data: complaintData
        });
      } catch(e){
        return res.json({
          success: 0,
          message: 'No Data Fetched',
          data: []
        });
      }
    },

  getLogs: async (req, res) => {
        try{
          const id = req.query.id
          const result = await getLogs(id); //from service.js (an sql query)
          var feedbackData = result[0][0];
          
          return res.set({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).status(200).json({
            success: 1,
            message: 'Successfully Data Fetched',
            data: logs
          });
        } catch(e){
          return res.json({
            success: 0,
            message: {text:'No Data Fetched ', errMsg: e.message},
            data: []
          });
        }
    },
```

> routes //node js express js
> app.js

```
app.use('/serviceCall', serviceCallRoute);
```

> serviceCallRoute

```
router.get("/getList", getList);
router.get("/getDetails", getDetails);
router.get("/getTroubles", getTroubles);
router.get("/getLogs", getLogs);
```

> angular subscribe to api

```
getServiceCalls() {
    return this.http.get(url + 'serviceCall/getList',this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map((res: IServiceCall) => {
          return res;
        }),
        catchError(errorRes => {
          return throwError(errorRes);
        })
      );
  }

  getServiceCallDetails(id):Observable<IServiceCall> {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('id', id);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    return this.http.get(url + 'serviceCall/getDetails',{headers:headers,params: params})
      .pipe(
        map((res: IServiceCall) => {
          return res;
        }),
        catchError(errorRes => {
          return throwError(errorRes);
        })
      );
  }
  getServiceCallTroubles(id) {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('id', id);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    return this.http.get<IServiceCallTroubles>(url + 'serviceCall/getTroubles',{headers:headers,params: params})
      .pipe(
        map((res: IServiceCallTroubles) => {
          return res;
        }),
        catchError(errorRes => {
          return throwError(errorRes);
        })
      );
  }
  getServiceCallLogs(id):Observable<IServiceCallLogs>{
    const params = new HttpParams().set('id', id);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    return this.http.get<IServiceCallLogs>(url + 'serviceCall/getLogs',{headers:headers,params: params})
      .pipe(
        map((res: IServiceCallLogs) => {
          return res;
        }),
        catchError(errorRes => {
          return throwError(errorRes);
        })
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The express js is working well. It is fault in database connection limit.

the DB connection limit was set as 10. So,after 10 api request with sql query. The db connection gets disconnected.